# Magento2.0.7 how to add header and footer to checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, header, magento-2.0.7

My override file

`Mystore/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
   <!-- <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true"/> -->
    <!-- <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/> -->
  <!--  <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/> -->      
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>   
   <!-- <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/> -->
</body>
</page>
```

It is not adding header to checkout page.Suggest some solution.

Comment: have you found correct solution for it? or have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Please set remove="false" instead of commenting that line.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
      <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
      <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
      <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
</body>
</page>
```

try this,
and let me know if not working

and path sould  be like this.

```
 {Magento2_root}app/design/frontend/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml
```

Comment: @zest Please check my updated answer. and let me know if not work.

Comment: Its doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

use the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
    <!-- <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" /> -->
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.links2" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true" />    
    <move element="logo" as="logo" destination="ves_header"/>

    <!-- <referenceBlock name="ves.footer.top" remove="true" /> -->
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Its doesnt work.